# ¿Como obtengo mi usuario de Spring security para mostrar o no cierta informacion en pantalla?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, spring-security

En mi app web con thymeleaf busco que un botón aparezca o desaparezca según si un usuario inicio sesión o no.

Si no lo hizo que simplemente muestre la vista y en caso de hacerlo que le habilite el botón para poder editarlo y/o eliminarlo.

El usuario está configurado desde el `application.properties`.

Sé que para mostrarlo o no puedo usar un `th:if="condicion"`.

La condición seria **si el usuario esta activo --> mostrar**, lo que no se, es como obtener el usuario activo o al menos su estado de activo que supongo que se hace desde el controlador, aunque no sé cómo.

Aquí mi configuración de seguridad

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig{
    
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .requestMatchers("/noticias/newNoticia").hasRole("USER")
            .requestMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
        .build();
}

}
```

*cabe aclarar, como el  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` quedo obsoleto, estoy un poco perdido con la nueva configuración*

Answer (score 0):

primero debes usar los módulos extras de thymeleaf security importándolos al inicio de tu pagina html así:

```
<html xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
```

Luego ya podrías usar tu condicional para mostrar elementos html, por ejemplo :

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> * Esto solo será visible para usuarios logeados * </div>
```

Espero que sea de ayuda, si quieres más información puedes consultar la documentación de thymeleaf, o usar este [articulo](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-user-info)